# Lotus Notes script "Alarms": check status

Tags: lotus-notes

i want to know if is there a method or field if the form "Appointment" in the users mail database where i can see if an alarms is expired or not... i know that "$alarms" folder contains only the alarms that are not displayed yet but is there another method in lotus notes script to determinate the status of each alarms?
Thank's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no single item to show, if an alarm is "pending". If a document has the item `$Alarms`, then an alarm is enabled. If you check the Column in the $Alarms- Folder you see, how the alarm- datetime is calculated:

```
@If(@IsAvailable($AlarmTime); $AlarmTime;
Form = "Task"; @Adjust(DueDateTime; 0; 0; 0; 0; $AlarmOffset; 0);
@Adjust(CalendarDateTime; 0; 0; 0; 0; $AlarmOffset; 0))
```

Either there is an item called `$AlarmTime` or one called `$AlarmOffset` used to calculate the alarms.

BUT: If the items are there, but for one reason, the document is not in the $Alarms- Folder anymore, then no alarm will fire.

In the [IBM Lotus Notes and Domino Calendaring & Scheduling Schema](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/cs_schema_toc) there is a section about all [alarm items](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/cs_schema_index#alarm) where you can find detailled description about every single item involved in "alarming".